# What is the ViewController.swift (Interface) file for - in Counterparts

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I just noticed that a file called `ViewController.swift (Interface)` was created automatically by Xcode when I created my first ViewController.

Do classes in Swift have/need interfaces the same as in Objective-C and are created behind the scenes by Xcode?

Can someone be so kind and explain what is the purpose of this file?

**ViewController.swift (Interface)**

```
import UIKit

internal class ViewController : UIViewController {

    override internal func viewDidLoad()

    override internal func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C and Objective-C, you have separate *interface* (.h) and *implementation* (.c, .m) files.

1. **The interface file** gives a quick view of all the methods and properties of that class that are available to other code (provided they import the interface file). It is like the chapter index of a book.
2. **The implementation**, on the other hand, is where the actual method code is written.

**In Swift**, on the other hand, there is no such distinction and classes are automatically available to all your code. The advantage is, of course, that the number of source files in your project is roughly cut in half, and you don't need to go back and forth between the interface file and implementation file while coding (it's all "in one place").

So, to make up for the lack of an "interface-only" file (like the headers in C/Objective-C), Xcode generates one "on the fly" just for the purpose of showing you the available methods and properties of that class. You will notice that method bodies are missing, as well as properties and methods declared as `private` (because they are inaccessible outside of the class, hence by definition not part of the "interface").

It is not a real file that resides anywhere in your file system (as far as I know).

Comment: Interesting, so it is like a quick-summary that lets you know what methods or properties you are exposing to the outside world (or between projects), I can see this being a killer feature when creating APIs/frameworks, especially because Swift doesn't require interface files. Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: Appreciated, good explanation. I personally would still prefer an outline view for the type in the navigator panel, as it's provided by Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 2):

In swift you don't have separate interface (or header files) and implementation files. You just create the class interface and implementation together in the same file. Other parts of the project, will automatically get access to the type introduced in a given file.

Now coming to the ViewController.Swift, this is the file where your view's controller layer logic goes. Please refer this documentation-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/